Excel export not working after upgrading react ag grid to 32.2.0
I was earlier using 28.0.1 of react ag grid. I upgraded to 32.2.0 and now gridApi.exportDataAsExcel() is not working. It's giving error as - unable to export as package ag-grid-enterprise has not been imported. I have already imported it in my index.js alog with license key and also in my custom.js to test, but any detailed working example will help.
Importing in many files where ever dependancy is there

If you want a worked example, have you checked the aggrid website?

Yes. I did not find anything in the website
